# web.xml not found. Mock struts test case

Tags: java, junit, mocking, struts, web.xml

This is my project directory structure:

```
TOPS-WEB
      |___
      |    Java Resources
      |___ 
           WebContent
                 |____
                      WEB-INF
                            |____
                            |    web.xml
                            |____  
                            |    lib
                            |       |__
                            |          strutstest-2.1.4.jar
                            |____
                                 struts
                                      |__
                                         struts-info-config.xml
```

When I run my test I get the following error. This error is thrown by line 
setServletConfig(...) in the testInfo() method.

```
ERROR [main] org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet initServlet - The /WEB-INF/web.xml was not found.
ERROR [main] org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet init - Unable to initialize Struts ActionServlet due to an unexpected exception or error thrown, so marking the servlet as unavailable.  Most likely, this is due to an incorrect or missing library dependency.
```

My Test Class

```
public class MyTest extends MockStrutsTestCase{

    @Override
    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();           
    }

    @Override
    protected void tearDown() throws Exception {
        super.tearDown();
    }

    public MyTest(String testName){
        super(testName);
    }

    public void testInfo(){         
        setContextDirectory(new File("TOPS-WEB/WebContent"));       
        setConfigFile(this.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("/WEB-INF/struts/struts-info-config.xml"));         
        *setServletConfigFile(this.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("/WEB-INF/web.xml"));*
        setRequestPathInfo("/infoPopup");
        actionPerform();            
        }    
    }
```

I saw some places where it was mentioned that you have to use maven but I am not. I just right click on the test class and run it as junit. Could that be the reason?

Comment: Does `new File("TOPS-WEB/WebContent").exists()` return `true`? Might be a case of an incorrect working directory.

Comment: I did System.out.println(new File("TOPS-WEB/WebContent").exists()); and it returned false.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you're setting the context directory (using `setContextDirectory`) to a path that doesn't exist.

`new File(string)`, when the `string` is a relative pathname, will resolve to a path name that is relative to the current working directory. You are assuming, then, that the current working directory is the parent directory of where Tomcat places its exploded WAR files.

Print this:

`System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir"))`

And you'll get the process' current working directory. Then, adjust `setContextDirectory` accordingly.